# Call Pop-Up for WebDynpro from a Business AddIn?

Tags: abap, webdynpro, badi

We got a Web Dynpro Application which was created with the Floorplan Manager.
By clicking a specific button I start a Business AddIn which check some conditions and then it should show a popup on the screen with a message for the user.
Is there a way I can accomplish that?

Comment: Why not? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey, sry for the late reply. I got distracted by something else. I tried to call a pop-up like in a normal report such as "POPUP_TO_CONFIRM". But obviously this won't work when I do that in my function because the WD lies in a FPM. So i need to get a connection to the WD which is currently active. So far i couldn't quite figure out how to create a pop up in this FPM WebDynpro. :/

Answer (score 0):

One way to get a PopUp (eg confirmation) window in Floorplan applications is to overwrite the **NEEDS_CONFIRMATION** method of the Interface **IF_FPM_GUIBB_*_EXT** inside your feeder-class.

Create a reference to **cl_fpm_confirmation_request** and put this one in the export-parameter **EO_CONFIRMATION_REQUEST** of the Method.

By Example:

```
METHOD if_fpm_guibb_list_ext~needs_confirmation.

DATA li_req TYPE REF TO cl_fpm_confirmation_request.

CASE io_event->mv_event_id.
WHEN 'YOUR_EVENT_ID'.

CREATE OBJECT li_req
  EXPORTING
    it_confirmation_text   = 'Plaintext in Content of Popup'
    iv_window_title        = 'Title of the Popup'
    iv_button_text_approve = 'Text Approve-Button'
    iv_button_text_reject  = 'Text Reject-Button'
    .

eo_confirmation_request = li_confrequ.

ENDCASE.
ENDMETHOD.
```

The method will be called before the **PROCESS_EVENT**-Method an will override it when you cancel the popup.

Please be aware that every GUIBB-Implementation has it´s own extension interface, e.g. List, Tree, ...

For a deeper look inside popups in FPM or custom-popups have a look into https://blogs.sap.com/2013/11/26/popups-in-floorplan-manager/